# C Linked List temporary variable

Tags: c, variables, linked-list

I'm trying to put a linked list node into a temporary variable, but, when I edit the temp variable `test`, the original `currentstate` variable also changes.

Here is the code:

```
struct states * BFSearch(struct states* initial)
{
  int i = 0, j = 0,k=0,l=0;
  struct states* currentstate = (struct states*)malloc(sizeof(struct states));
  struct states* temp = (struct states*)malloc(sizeof(struct states));
  Enqueue(initial);             

  while(front != NULL && rear != NULL)
  {
    currentstate = Dequeue();

    if (GoalTest(currentstate))
    { 
        return(currentstate);
    }                                                           
    else
    {                                               
        for(i = 0; i<5; i++)
        {
            for(j = 0; j<5; j++)
            {
                if (currentstate->toggled[i][j] == 0)
                {
                    test = currentstate;
                    test->puzzle[0][0] = 3;
                    for (k = 0; k < 5; k++)
                    {
                            for (l = 0; l < 5; l++)
                            {
                                printf("%d ", currentstate->puzzle[k][l]);
                            }
                            printf("\n");
                    }
                    printf("\n");

                    for (k = 0; k < 5; k++)
                    {
                            for (l = 0; l < 5; l++)
                            {
                                printf("%d ", test->puzzle[k][l]);
                            }
                            printf("\n");
                    }
                    printf("\n");
                }
            }
        }   
    }
  }
}
```

The `currentstate` puzzle looks like this:

> 0 0 0 0 0
>      0 0 1 0 0
>      0 1 1 1 0
>      0 0 1 0 0
>      0 0 0 0 0

But, when I just change the `test` to `test->puzzle[0][0] = 3`, both of them, `test` and `currentstate`, turn to this:

> 3 0 0 0 0
>      0 0 1 0 0
>      0 1 1 1 0
>      0 0 1 0 0
>      0 0 0 0 0

Comment: I see no declaration for `test`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the bug is here:

```
            if (currentstate->toggled[i][j] == 0){
                test = currentstate;
                test->puzzle[0][0] = 3;
```

It should be instead:

```
            if (currentstate->toggled[i][j] == 0){
                *test = *currentstate;
                test->puzzle[0][0] = 3;
```

When you do:

```
test = currentstate;
```

Then test point to the same address of `currentstate`, if you do:

```
*test  =  *currentstate;
```

You are copying the content pointed by `currentstate` to the content pointed by `test`

Comment: Assigning `test = currentstate` is not making a copy of the data. Both variables are pointers, so they both point to the same area of memory. So updating one is reflected in the other.

Comment: @JamesLiam  If his answer solved your problem, you might want to upvote and/or [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) it.